# Do larger transactions or more compute units slow down transactions?

Tags: transactions

I want my dapp to be as fast as possible.

As i'm adding more complexity/size im wondering if a larger transaction or a transaction requesting more compute units get processed / confirmed slower than smaller transactions.

Or would a large transaction be just as fast as a small transaction as long as they stay within the size limit and compute budget limit?

Extra question: would using address lookup tables speed up or slow down transactions? As they add a layer of indirection I could imagine they make them slower?

Answer (score 0):

Leaders may choose to include or order transactions however they wish for the most part. There are two main limits in place at the network level:

- the total number of compute units used by one account in a block is capped at 12M https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/8330dee95d025dcf6e75a3d5ac538bda9a3d9e70/cost-model/src/block_cost_limits.rs#L72
- the total number of compute units in a block is 48M https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/8330dee95d025dcf6e75a3d5ac538bda9a3d9e70/cost-model/src/block_cost_limits.rs#L64

Until your accounts get close to the 12M per block limit, they *should* be ok, but validators may implement other block-packing schemes to prioritize cheap transactions and collect more fees.

To get around that, you can have your users include prioritization fees to incentivize leaders to include your transactions: https://docs.solana.com/transaction_fees#prioritization-fee